# How to get a value from a document in mongo DB

Tags: c#, .net, database, mongodb

I'm making a registration system (mongoDB) with a discord bot, the registration works perfectly so now i have to make the login. The login will be in c# with Mongo Driver.

The schema is:

```
username: String,
password: String
```

Is there a way to get the password of a document by filtering it with the username?

The code:

```
MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient( < connection string > );

Console.Write("LOGIN\nusername ~> ");
var username = Console.ReadLine();

//Console.Write("\npassword ~> ");
//var password = Console.ReadLine();

var database = dbClient.GetDatabase("database");
var collection = database.GetCollection < BsonDocument > ("accounts");

var filter = Builders < BsonDocument > .Filter.Eq("username", username);

var doc = collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Do you reach the user into `doc` variable?

Comment: yes, how can i get the password value as a string

Comment: What is the value from `Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());`?, is the password there?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Can you do `doc.password` (assuming `doc` is not null) to get the password?

Comment: uhh, i feel kinda dumb by saying that, but sorry, i dont understand

Comment: BsonDocument (`doc`) supports indexer. Also, you may use a set of `Get..`/`TryGet..` methods

Comment: so how do i get the password value?

Comment: You can try this: `doc.GetValue("password").AsString`

Comment: It worked, you really helped me, thxx :D